# Change of basis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Given two basis matrices `basis_old` and `basis_new` in numpy, is there a function somewhere in the library to get the transformation matrix to convert a vector `vec` in `basis_old` to its representation in `basis_new`?

For example, if I have a vector `vec = [1,2,3]` in the standard basis `[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]`, how to I convert it to another basis, say,

```
e1 = [1 0 0]
e2 = [0 0 1]
e3 = [0 1 0]
basis_new = np.array([e1, e2, e3])

# I want something like this
vec_new = np.linalg.change_of_basis(vec_old, basis_old, basis_new)

# Or this:
transformation_matrix = np.linalg.basis_change(basis_old, basis_new)
```

Edit: changed basis_new to be linearly independent

Comment: Isn't it just a dot product?

Comment: Your `basis_new` is not a basis ;-). From standard basis coords to another basis you can use `linalg.solve`.

Comment: Your *new* `basis_new` still isn't a basis.

Comment: I meant for each row to be a basis vector (and I'm bad at math <facepalm emoji here>). I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic but for a square matrix the rows are l.i. if and only if the columns are l.i.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remember what it means for a set of vectors w1, w2, w3 to be a basis of R3.

1. The w's must be [*linearly independent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). That means the only solution to x1 w1 + x2 w2 + x3 w3 = 0 should be x1 = x2 = x3 = 0. But in your case, you can verify that x1 = 1, x2 = -2, x3 = 1 is another solution. So your `basis_new` is not valid.
2. The matrix W = [w1, w2, w3] must be invertible.
3. For every vector in R3 there must be a *unique* way to write it as a linear combination of w's.

Once you have nailed these requirements for a basis, then you can compute the new coordinates by a simple matrix multiplication. Suppose you want to express vector v as v = c1 w1 + c2 w2 + c3 w3. To write this in matrix form, v = W c. To get c, all you have to do is to multiply both side by the inverse of W.

c = W^{-1} v

In numpy, you would write it as,

```
vec_new = np.linalg.inv(np.column_stack((w1, w2, w3))).dot(vec_old)
```

Comment: One can alternatively use `np.linalg.solve(W, v)` to avoid performing matrix inversion.