# Rotate one 3D coordinate system to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, linear-algebra, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of points in one coordinate system and I want to rotate them to another coordinate system in Python. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392459/3173758) I wrote the following Python function:

```
def change_of_basis(points, initial, final):
    '''
    rotate points/vectors in a 3D coordinate system to a new coordinate system

        input: m x 3 array of points or vectors that have to be transformed from the initial to the final csys
        initial: sequence of sequences of floats representing the normalized axis of the csys that has to be transformed
        final: sequence of sequences of floats representing the normalized axis of the csys to which has to be transformed

        return: the points/vectors in the new coordinate system
    '''
    x1, y1, z1 = initial
    x2, y2, z2 = final

    M11, M12, M13 = np.dot(x1, x2), np.dot(x1, y2), np.dot(x1, z2)
    M21, M22, M23 = np.dot(y1, x2), np.dot(y1, y2), np.dot(y1, z2)
    M31, M32, M33 = np.dot(z1, x2), np.dot(z1, y2), np.dot(z1, z2)

    # set up rotation matrix
    R = np.array([[M11, M12, M13],
                  [M21, M22, M23],
                  [M31, M32, M33]])

    return np.linalg.inv(R).dot(points)
```

Running example:

```
  initial =  [[ 0.98078528  0.         -0.19509032]
             [-0.19509032  0.         -0.98078528]
             [ 0.          1.          0.        ]]

  final =  [[ 0.83335824 -0.08626633 -0.54595986]
            [-0.55273325 -0.13005679 -0.82314712]
            [ 0.          0.98774564 -0.15607226]]


   new_cys = change_of_basis(initial, initial, final )
```

Plotting this gives the result visualized below. The intention is to transform the red/orange coordinate system to the yellow one but the result is the blue coordinate system. Can anyone see what mistake I am making and how to fix this?

[image]

EDIT:
It worked to transform the coordinate system. I changed to the function above to what I have now. It allows me to transform the red to the yellow coordinate system. Now what I need is to transform a set of points in the first (red) coordinate system to a set of points in the second (yellow) coordinate system. I thought that this function would work but it does not, is the transformation different for a set of points?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in linear algebra, but I think your mistake is in not inverting the initial coordinate system.

If A and B are your basis matrices, you are computing A * B, but what you need to compute is A^{-1} * B.

Which makes sense - you multiply by A^{-1} to convert to the standard basis from A, then multiply by B to convert to from the standard basis to B.

Here's another SO answer that talks about implementing this: [Change of basis in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082928/change-of-basis-in-numpy)

EDIT: Peculiar that this version worked for the coordinate system. It's not R you need to invert. You are computing R = A * B, so so by inverting R you get A^{-1} * B^{-1}. You need to invert A first, *then* multiply.

Comment: I managed to do the transformation using the link you provided. When I tried to apply the rotation to my point cloud it didn't work (see edit). Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try using the transpose of the matrix to rotate your point cloud. See [Rotation Matrix](https://www.continuummechanics.org/rotationmatrix.html#:%7E:text=A%20transformation%20matrix%20describes%20the,the%20transpose%20of%20the%20other.), which suggests that the matrix used to rotate the coordinate system and the matrix used to rotate an object are transposes of each other. The link also has useful information about defining a general transform matrix between two coordinate systems:
[picture of general transform matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EgGq.png)
and the rotation matrix (which is the transpose):
[picture of general rotation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVlOl.png)
"where (x′,x) represents the angle between the x′ and x axes, (x′,y) is the angle between the x′ and y axes, etc."

[How to get the rotation matrix to transform between two 3d cartesian coordinate systems?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26085) talks about using the identity transform as a reference between two coordinate systems when neither coordinate system is the coordinate system defined by the orthonormal vectors: (1,0,0); (0,1,0); (0,0,1)

Comment: Please, explain more and tell about the reasons of functionality of your suggestion.